# Text Widget - How to avoid text being parsed as special characters

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

This may seem a weird question, but I really don't know how to search this one.

Imagine that I have this Widget:

```
Text("Career highlights (9)")
```

This is being shown as this:

[image]

How can I show a simple (9) insted of what is shown?

Comment: in which platform this output is coming from? I can see the expected text in `web` and `iOS` platform without any change made with your code.

Comment: @DineshNagarajan On Android (API 27, A 8.1)

Comment: Can you check if the device is using the default font family or any custom font? Also, are you using any custom font for your app? From the screenshot, it looks like you're using a custom font for your app.

Comment: This could be because of the font you are using. check the font characters.

Comment: @OMiShah - You are right - its from the font. Is there a way to escape it?

Comment: try printing text as raw like this ``Text(r'Career highlights (9)')`` or adding a backslash before ``9``

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Text("Career highlights \(9\)")
```